# Could the collision of two pairs of quantum entangled protons cause a temporary "wormhole"?

Tags: particle-physics, string-theory, black-holes, quantum-entanglement, wormholes

I recently read [this](http://newsoffice.mit.edu/2013/you-cant-get-entangled-without-a-wormhole-1205) article from MIT News. I then started thinking about how a particle accelerator creates a temporary [microscopic black hole](http://press.web.cern.ch/backgrounders/safety-lhc).

My question is:

> *If quantum entangled pair $A$, consisting of $A_1$ and $A_2$, and a second pair $B$, consisting of $B_1$ and $B_2$, were collided, $A_1$ collides with $B_1$, and $A_2$ collides with $B_2$, would this create a temporary wormhole?*

Comment: This question is related to the recently in legitimate (!) theoretical physics discovered [ER/EPR correspondance](http://motls.blogspot.de/search?q=ER/EPR). There is absolutely nothing non-mainstream about it.

Comment: @Gummybears yes, wormholes and black-holes are related by the ER/EPR correspondance I mentioned above, there is no wording problem at all.

Comment: @Dilaton Sorry I seemed to have read it wrong the first time. I misunderstood the way that 'blackhole' was used. Sorry!